# What type of control(s) gives first time users a walkthrough of the app? Can it be automated?

Tags: android, appium, android-uiautomator

We see a lot of apps which show a help kind of feature to provide a walkthorugh of the application. In the attached Image of the CricBuzz application, one such control can be seen.

- Image

[image: Image here].

My questions are:

Is this a regular Android Control with opacity set?
Is this related to the [OnBoardingSupportFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/OnboardingSupportFragment)
Why is the control not being recognized by Appium or UIAutomatorViewer?
Can this control be automated/verified by Appium?